# WPF application I want to reproduce "Error Details: The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway"

Tags: c#, wpf, rest

I have WPF (with .NET framework 3.5) application communicating with web service. At client side, following errors are coming:

1. The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway.
2. The remote server returned an error: (504) Gateway Timeout.

These error are not reproducible in dev environment. How can I reproduce these errors by just changing the web.config file of web service.

Hint: At client side it takes some time to process the request and send a response from web server to WPF application. This was also tried locally, but still these errors are not reproduced.

Comment: Already set the following tag, but still not get the error:


<httpRuntime executionTimeout="1"/>

Comment: what is the hosting? any nginx or haproxy in the way?

Comment: Its hosted on IIS 10.0, and this error doesnot comes always. It comes randomly.